# Cast forwardly-declared pointer to more specific type

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class like

```
class Shape;
class Triangle;
class Amorpher
{
public:
    Amorpher();
    Amorpher(Shape*);
    Amorpher(Shape&);
    ~Amorpher();
    Shape* pShape;
    void GetShapeArea();
    void Shapeshift(Shape&, string);
    void Shapeshift(Shape*, string);
private:
    Triangle* triangle;
};
```

and the implementation

```
Amorpher::Amorpher()
{
}
Amorpher::Amorpher(Shape* shape) : pShape(shape){}
void Amorpher::GetShapeArea()
{
    cout << "shape area is: " << pShape->Area();

}

Amorpher::~Amorpher()
{
}
void Amorpher::Shapeshift(Shape* shape,string shiftTo)
{
    if (shiftTo == "triangle")
    {
        (Triangle*)shape = triangle;
    }
}
```

Triangle inherits from shape.  I want in the Shapeshift method to try to cast the Shape passed into the method to a Triangle. Not all Shapes will be Triangles, but why can't I explicitly make this cast?  Does forward declaration have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: `triangle = (Triangle*)shape`

Comment: What are you trying to do in Shapeshift exactly?

Comment: @Barry just get down syntax and semantics, really.  I don't have all the rules down for what you and and can't do with forward declarations and I didn't know if I was allowed to do what I tried.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Syntax of *what*? Are you trying to assign `triangle` to `shape`? `shape` to `triangle`? Is `pShape` involved?

Comment: @Barry I was trying to change the type of Shape passed into the Shapeshift method to a pointer that matches the string parameter in the same function.  pShape wasn't involved, I was wanting to practice chasing pointers.

Comment: I would consider skipping the `shiftTo` argument in the `ShapeShift` method as it is potentially redundant. The type you want to shapeshift to can be directly inferred from the type of the `shape` passed in. Use `typeid()` to infer this property.

Answer (score 1):

> I was trying to change the type of Shape passed into the Shapeshift method to a pointer that matches the string parameter in the same function

The safe cast is `dynamic_cast`:

```
dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(shape);
```

If `shape` is a `Triangle*`, this will succeed and result of the expression will be a valid pointer. Else, it will be a null pointer.

The unsafe cast would be `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<Triangle*>(shape);
```

This would be undefined behavior if `shape` happened to not be a `Triangle*`, but would be a non-null pointer regardless (as long as `shape` was non-null).

Comment: Note that `dynamic_cast<>` only works for polymorphic types related by inheritance, neither of which is clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since `(Triangle *)shape` is not a modifiable l-value, you cannot assign a value to it.
What you probably wanted to do is

```
triangle = (Triangle*)shape;
```

Don't use C-Style casts though as they prevent you from running into several runtime errors.
Better use `dynamic_cast` in this case.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts in C++.

Comment: @DDrmmr yes, thank you. I thought that was obvious because of Barry's answer.